# Pre populating editable django admin form from other table

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, django-admin

[image: this is the django admin panel with a table named Committees]

this is the django admin panel with a table named Committees.
there is a field named committee type in committees table.

There is a table named default, with the model defined below,

```
class default(models.Model):
    committee_type = models.CharField()
    description = models.CharField()
    quorum = models.InetgerField()
```

What i wanted to do is, 
1) when i select the committee type to city council in committees table in admin(like in screenshot), I wanted to populate the description and quorum from the default table in to the description and quorum in committees table in the admin itself 
2) these populated data should be retrieved from default table where the committee type is city council
3) these fields should be editable in the committees table in admin after getting populated from the default table and should be able to be saved in this committee object

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can [set the initial value for the field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/#initial) to what you'd like. As noted in the docs, you can set the initial value to a callable so that it will call that callable when the form is instantiated and pre-fill the returned value in the field. The callable could be a function that retrieves the data from the database for the appropriate field. This would happen for new committees (which will use unbound forms) and not for existing committees you want to edit (which will use bound forms).

Because this is the admin, the form class to be used can be set with the [`ModelAdmin.form` attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form), which should be set to a customized ModelForm class for the appropriate model.

If you just want to set initial data and don't have a lot of other customization to do on this particular admin form, you can override the [`ModelAdmin.get_changeform_initial_data` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_changeform_initial_data), instead.

Comment: I dont want to do this in **forms**. The screenshot i posted is of the django admin panel. i want to achieve this functionality in the django admin. 

once i select the committe type in the committee table(like in screenshot), the description and quorum **django admin fields like in screenshot**  should be automatically filled with the data that i want to fetch from a other table named default.

Comment: I've edited the answer to clarify how to do this for the form used by the ModelAdmin subclass you're using, as well as a way you can try that doesn't involve having to write a custom form class.

Answer (score 0):

as the admin panel will be used in by the client on their pc, this could be implemented using a custom js/jquery event listener on the dropdown. When the dropdown value is changed, ajax call will be made to the server(send the selected option) which will return the required data that can be populated in the front end using jquery. You will have to write a function/view in the views.py file that will return the json of committee_type, description and quorum.

You will have to add this custom js to the template of the edit page of the admin page in question manually. I dont know the best way to do this, maybe override the template page in question, keep everything the same and just add a link to the custom js function of the above code.

Hope this helps.